# questions on solving exponential equations

Tags: exponential-function

I have these questions on exponentials and I wanted to know if I am correct..

**1. $2^{3-x} = 565$**

$3-x\log 2 =\log 565$

$3-x =\frac{\log 565}{\log 2}$

$x = 3-\frac{\log 565}{\log 2}$

**2. $(1+\frac{.1}{12})^{12t}=2$**

$12t \log (1+12) = \log 2$

$12 t (\log 12) = \log 2$

$t = \frac{\log 2}{12
\log 12}$

**3. $6e^{1-x}-25=0$**

$6(1-x)\ln e = \ln 25$

$6(1-x) = \ln (5^2)$

$6(1-x) = 2\ln 5$

$x = 1-\frac{2\ln 5}{6}$

**4. $e^{0.09t}-3=0$**

$0.09t = \ln 3$

$t = \frac{\ln 3}{0.09}$

**5. $3e^{\frac{3x}{2}} -962=0$**

$e^{\frac{3x}{2}} = \frac{962}{3}$

$\frac{3x}{2} = \ln\frac{962}{3}$

$ x = 2/3 (\ln\frac{962}{3})$

Comment: Try number $2$ again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd one seems wrong.

$(1+\frac{1}{12})^{12t} = 2$

$12t\log (1+\frac{1}{12}) = \log2$

$12t\log (\frac{13}{12}) = 12t[\log13 - \log12] = \log2$

$t = \frac{\log2}{12(\log13-\log12)}$

And the 3rd one.

$6e^{1-x} = 25$

$\ln(6e^{1-x}) = \ln(25)$

$\ln(6) + (1-x) = \ln(25)$

$\ln(6) - \ln(25) + 1 = x$

$x = \ln(\frac{6}{25}) + 1$

Comment: thank you! is it incorrect to say ln(25) = 2 ln 5?

Comment: Yeah that's correct but $ln(6e^{1-x}) = ln(6) + ln(e^{1-x}) = ln(6) + 1-x$